# Netsuite Advanced PDF/Template - Display Item Group Only - No Kit Items

Tags: netsuite, freemarker, suitescript

We currently moved our packing slip from the basic PDF version to the Advanced PDF/HTML template and running into issues displaying the Item Group on the packing slip. The XML data on the Item Fulfillment only shows the kit items being fulfilled. We do not want to display the kit items but the Item Group the kit items are associated too.

Can someone please assist me with what I need to do to display the Item properly on the packing slip?

```
Setup Setting
1. On the Item Group record
   Purchasing/Inventory tab> Components subtab:
        Reference Start/End Lines on Picking Tickets = T (checked)
        Display Components on Transactions = F (unchecked)

2. Accounting Preferences 
   Setup> Accounting> Accounting Preferences>  Order Management tab> Picking/Packing:
        Show Non-Inventory Items on Printed Forms = F (unchecked)
```

The item group is on the sales order but the item group doesn't get to the fulfillment so it isn't included in the record object. Do I need to look at the sales order object to get the item group information?

Thank you!